# PDO on Db2 and mysql, call to fetch() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, db2

I'm running a script that has been working fine, last ran yesterday, and now I'm getting these errors when I run it:

> General error: 0 [IBM]psystem i access odbc driver] Undefined
>   variable: detailCheck call to a member function fetch() on null

All on the same line:

```
while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Again, it's been working fine, the connections are good, the tables exist and the queries all run manually. I haven't made any changes so I'm totally lost here

```
$ordStatSql = 'SELECT order_id, order_status, is_placement, date_updated 
            FROM order_status
            WHERE order_status = "S"
            AND date_updated IS NULL';
try{
$ordStat = $MysqlConn->prepare($ordStatSql);
$result = $ordStat->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

$order_ids = [];
while ($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
}

if (count($order_ids) > 0) {

$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($order_ids), '?'));
$detailStatCheck = "
    SELECT 
         invnoc as INVOICE,
         fstatc as STATUS,
         cstnoc AS DEALER,
         framec AS FRAME,
         covr1c AS COVER,
         colr1c AS COLOR ,
         extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
         orqtyc AS QUANTITY
    FROM GPORPCFL
    WHERE invnoc IN ($placeholders)
";

try {
    $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
    $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute($order_ids);
    $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
    print_r($order_ids);
    print_r($count2);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

//the below 'while' line is where I get the error
while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $values = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];

    $values2 = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],

    ];
```

Comment: This is weird: I changed the select that the query is based on to limit to 1000 and it worked fine

Comment: Have you set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: yes I have @DanielO. I just tried to use an iterator around my while loop to try batches of 1000 records but it still fails. It's like it sees how many records are coming from the select and then failing